# Why does a null value automatically get converted into empty string when using string.Join?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JArray that contains null values. And while I'm doing `string.Join`, `null` values are getting converted into `empty string`.

**Original array values:**

```
[
  null,
  null,
  "America/Boise",
  false,
  "2021-02-04T06:51:33.9686227Z"
]
```

**String.Join:**

```
var val = $"('{string.Join("','", valuesArray)}')";
```

**Current Result:**

```
"('','','America/Boise','False','2/4/2021 6:51:33 AM')"
```

**Expected Result:**

```
"(null,null,'America/Boise',False,'2/4/2021 6:51:33 AM')"
```

**Producing Example:**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nRTyL

How do I get the expected result using `string.Join`?

Comment: Hang on a sec. Are you trying to serialize your own json? If you are, dont...

Comment: no,just i have array of value like in question and doing string.Join

Comment: Instead of passing `valuesArray`, pass `valuesArray.Select(v => v ?? "null")`

Comment: Can you add a full minimal reproducible example, with test json and the code you are using (minimally). And this should be solved fairly quickly

Comment: @00110001 i have updated question reproducer with sample example

Comment: When you use String.Join all elements in the array will be converted to string. In this case you will get 
the result as ("", "America/Boise", "false",..) instead of (null,  "America/Boise", false,..), just like when you use a Convert.ToString() method.
If you need a "null" instead of "", then you can use intermediate select mentioned by @Youssef13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` values in a `JArray` are stored as `JTokens` with a `JTokenType` of `Null`.  So you'll need to check for this and convert them to the string `"null"`.  Secondly, since you only want to quote some of the values, you should not put the quotes in the separator value when you join them, but instead only quote the values that need it based on their types.

Define the following helper function:

```
string TokenToString(JToken token)
{
    switch (token.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Null: 
            return "null";
        case JTokenType.Date:
        case JTokenType.String: 
            return $"'{token}'";
        default: 
            return token.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can get the result you want like this:

```
string val = $"({string.Join(",", valuesArray.Select(v => TokenToString(v)))})";
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q62Uck

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how it was designed. See the documentation for [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___):

> If separator is null, an empty string (String.Empty) is used instead. **If any element in value is null, an empty string is used instead**.

Comment: how to achieve expected result?

Comment: just use Select and return literal "null" if the value is null

Answer (score 0):

just replace "''" to "null".

var val = $"('{string.Join("','", valuesArray)}')"**.Replace("''", "null")**;

Comment: wouldn't it also replace empty strings?

Comment: @hling i m looking for value ```null``` not for singlequoation null ```'null'```

Comment: @r08 replace '' two singlequoation => null, just fine in this case. or replace '', => null,